# Присвоение нескольких данных одному пользователю в PSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram, psycopg2

Пишу бота на python использую aiogram и psycopg2
Написал функцию которая добавляет присвоенные id, текстовые данные в поле

[image: Скрин из бд]

Функция сохранения:

```
def save_card (user_id, card):
with psycopg2.connect(****) as con:
    try:
        userid = user_id
        cards = card    
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE users SET card_t = %s WHERE user_id = %s", [cards, userid])
    except:
        print ('*')
        
if con:
        con.close
```

Вызов функции в хендлере:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == "sends_img")
async def input_text_prompt(clbck: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
     rnd = os.listdir('path_to_png/')
     rnd1 = random.choice(rnd)
     save_card(user_id=clbck.from_user.id, card=rnd1)
     photo = FSInputFile ('path_to_png/' + rnd1, 'rb')
     await clbck.message.answer_photo (photo)
     await clbck.message.answer ('123', reply_markup=kb.iexit_kb)
```

Сначала хотел записывать несколько данных в одну колонку (onepng.png, twopng.png и т.д.) но если правильно понял то это аномалия и это не совсем правильно,

Потом хотел записывать данные в JSON формате, но как оказалось потом будет сложно взаимодействовать с этими данными,

В конце концов попал в тупик как записывать новые картинки присвоенные user_id, картинок 20+ и каждый раз отправляется рандомная

важно чтобы с картинками можно было взаимодействовать (в дальнейшем реализовать галерею с сохраненными в бд фотками)

Comment: ну так должно быть две таблицы, одна для пользователей, другая для меты данных пользователей (ваших картинок), а далее уже гулять по списку картинок и сохранять каждую